# how to send pdf from view page to controller in php?

Tags: php, email, pdf, yii2, jspdf

i have created pdf using jsPDF plugin and can also download the pdf file and my question is how to send the generated pdf to an input of name post[attachment]

form to send

```
 <form method = "post" action="" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                                  <input type = "hidden" name = "<?php echo Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value = "<?php echo Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>"/>
                                  <input type = "hidden" name ="post[attachment]"   id="email">
                                  <input type = "hidden" name = "post[email]" value="<?php echo $d['booker']['email'] ?>">

                               </form>
                   <a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()"> <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-outline-secondary btn-preview noprint"  >Email</button></a>
```

This is my script code

```
<script>
   function demoFromHTML() {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
      source = $('#content')[0];
      specialElementHandlers = {
         '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
         }
      };
      margins = {
         top: 80,
         bottom: 60,
         left: 40,
         width: 522
      };
      pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
               'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
               'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },
            function (dispose) {
               var pdfBase64 = pdf.output('datauristring');
            }, margins
      );
   }
</script>
```

Comment: people are not understanding question or question is so hard to solve no one is replying?

Answer (score 1):

As you have created pdf on client side, i.e. in browser, you need to make an ajax call or submit the form to send file to the server (eventually to controller).

Comment: but we cannot send created pdf to controller as variable so im little bit confused

Comment: For anything you need to send from client/browser to server, you have to make http request for it. This http request can be form submission or can be an ajax call.

Comment: sir i used ajax to send the pdf file now what should i use to convert json data into pdf format . I have searched but couldn't get the right way